# Pinch zoom not working in UIScrollview for Multiple image in ios7

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, ios7

I want to pinch zoom in uiscrollview image. i added multiple image in uiscrollview 
but pinch zoom is not working i want to pinch zoom UIImageview image. i have refer so many reference but still its not working

Thanks in advance

My code:-

```
for(int i = 0;i<aryImage.count;i++)
            {

                 //Create a uiimageview

                imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]init ];

                imageView.frame = CGRectMake((280 *i),0.0, 280, 475);
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
                imageView.tag = i;
                imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [scrollGallery addSubview:imageView];

                scrollGallery.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;

                scrollGallery.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;

                scrollGallery.delegate = self;

               [scrollGallery addSubview:imageView];

            }
            scrollGallery.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280 * aryImage.count, scrollGallery.frame.size.height);
            pageControl.numberOfPages = aryImage.count;
            pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
            pageControl.currentPage = 0;




- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)sv
{
    UIView* zoomView = [sv.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:sv];
    CGRect zvf = zoomView.frame;
    if(zvf.size.width < sv.bounds.size.width)
    {
        zvf.origin.x = (sv.bounds.size.width - zvf.size.width) / 2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        zvf.origin.x = 0.0;
    }
    if(zvf.size.height < sv.bounds.size.height)
    {
        zvf.origin.y = (sv.bounds.size.height - zvf.size.height) / 2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        zvf.origin.y = 0.0;
    }
    zoomView.frame = zvf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return only one imageView in viewForZooming but you added an array of them. This may be the cause of your problem. Try to replace your code like this:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollGallery.frame];
[scrollGallery addSubview:containerView];
scrollGallery.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollGallery.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
scrollGallery.delegate = self;

for(int i = 0;i<aryImage.count;i++)
        {

             //Create a uiimageview

            imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]init ];

            imageView.frame = CGRectMake((280 *i),0.0, 280, 475);
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
            imageView.tag = i;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [containerView addSubview:imageView];
        }
        scrollGallery.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280 * aryImage.count, scrollGallery.frame.size.height);

        // then maybe you need to resize containerView's frame
        //..........

        pageControl.numberOfPages = aryImage.count;
        pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
        pageControl.currentPage = 0;


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return containerView;
}
```

Hope it will help.

**UPD**: also try to disable userInteraction of your imageViews. They may block interaction with scrollGallery.

**UPD2**: store all imageViews in predefined array. For, example,

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<aryImage.count; i++) {
    [arr addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] init]];
}
```

Then in your cycle instead of

```
imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

use

```
UIImageView *imageView = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
```

And don't forget to release everything at the end ;)

Comment: i use yr code it works for me but when i zoom third image then it not zoom it zoom only first image :)

Comment: Are you sure you're adding your third image to the container view rather than the scroll view?

Comment: @hatfinch yes i am adding all image in container view when i zoom third image then it return only first image :)

Comment: imageView object may be released in cycle cause you replace it by another object in next iteration. See UPD2 above.